# entity framework updating is not work

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a page.aspx that user see their information like name email and ... in that page.
when the page load I read info from database and save that obj in one session:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                using (MYEntities j = new MYEntities())
                {
                    int idOfUser = ///from session i read id of user
                    try
                    {
                        InfoOfUser info = (from i in j.InfoOfUsers where i.UserID == idOfUser select i).Single();
                        Session["info"] =info ; 
                        ///set information to my  page controls(txtbxs and ...)
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
                    {
                        /// do ...
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                    {
                        /// do ...
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

I have an edit button taht in click event of that:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MYEntities j = new MYEntities())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        InfoOfUser info=Session["info"] as InfoOfUser; 
                        info.Name=textboxName.Text;
                        ///
                        ///set inforamtion to info
                        ///
                        j.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
                    {
                        /// do ...
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                    {
                        /// do ...
                    }
                }
    }
```

The problem is that it does not store in my database. Where is my code wrong? And when it stored info. How can I remove that session? I can not remove that session after saving
because I can click **Edit** button more than once. And when user goes to another page how can I remove that session?

Comment: You don't attach `info` to the context.

Comment: which version of EF?

Comment: my entity framework is vesion5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First attach entity to context then save

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MYEntities j = new MYEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    InfoOfUser info=Session["info"] as InfoOfUser; 
                    j.InfoOfUsers.Attach(info);
                    info2.Name=textboxName.Text;
                    ///
                    ///set inforamtion to info
                    ///
                    j.SaveChanges();
                    Session.Remove("info");
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
                {
                    /// do ...
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    /// do ...
                }
            }
}
```

This will work.

**Update**

To remove session, assign `Session.Remove("info");` after successful edit.